# JSP changes not reflecting when server is run. (JBoss, Maven, Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, maven, jboss

I don't think the issue is isolated solely to my JSPs. However, the current files I'm trying to edit are JSPs.

Whenever I make changes to my JSP, I save the file (in Eclipse), clean/republish my JBoss server, start the server, and access the application (localhost), yet the changes I made are not reflected on the page at all.

I go to the JBoss temp directory to see exactly what version of the file (that I'm editing) the server is currently using. I always see that it's using the original version that I pulled down from the original repo. I have no idea why it's not changing.

I tried re-cloning and re-importing everything just out of desperation, and I'm getting the same results.

In addition, strangely, when I run the command `mvn -U clean package -DskipTests=true` to do a command-line build using Maven, my file reverts back to the original/unchanged version. (New to Maven, so it's strange to me at least).

So, essentially any changes I am making to files for my project aren't being reflected on my local test server. I'm totally stumped as to why it's behaving like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put JBoss in development mode.  This is a mode in which JSPs are always re-compiled.  Thus when you deploy a JSP change, you can immediately see it.

For JBoss 7, edit the file: /jboss/{server_name}/configuration/standalone.xml.  Locate the "jsp-configuration" element and set the "development" attribute to true.

```
        <configuration>
            <jsp-configuration development="true" x-powered-by="false"/>
        </configuration>
```

Note:

- This file is in a different location in different versions of JBoss.
- {server_name} in the path above will be specific to your JBoss install. If you have not created a server, then this value is likely "default" for you.  You can easily find this value by looking at where your web app is deployed.
- It is a good idea to deploy your web application in "exploded" format.  That is, rather than deploying it as a WAR file (which takes time to build), explode (i.e. unzip) the contents of the web app right in the JBoss deployment area.  That way when you need to make a JSP change, you simply copy the one JSP file.